# Why did the cookie disagree popup start to be delayed by several hundred milliseconds?

Tags: support, cookies

For several days now I notice a delay when opening the cookie-disagree popup. Before it felt instantaneous, but now there is a noticeable delay of nearly a second—enough to wonder whether the click failed and to re-click.

What changed?

Before all is set and done, over one second elapsed:

[image]

Comment: [There is about 100ms processing server-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuvkA.png). Not sure what this means, though.

Comment: "Cookie disagree popup?" Oh you rebel you.